# encodeURIComponent Not working properly NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encoding, uri

I'm trying to encode text of biography for Instagram change biography on profile and it doesnt accept my biography.

I used:

```
let bio = "111X@%(!#)!$(*!Gram)"
let biography = encodeURIComponent(bio)
```

and it failing. Need help please

[Java equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent that produces identical output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607176/java-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-that-produces-identical-outpu)

I need this but for NodeJS, so it generate same encoding as Java one.

Answer (score 0):

There are some distinctions between Java's URI encoding and the JS `encodeURIComponent` functions. Spaces will translate to `+` in Java but they will translate to `%20` in Javascript. The JS function uses UTF-8 by default, but Java could be using a different format for encoding (depending on your code editor). Take a look at this stack overflow post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298843/9571755

Hope that helps and happy coding :)